# How to retrieve all non deleted file form Repo using git

Tags: git

I am using `git ls-files` to list all the file indexed by git in a repository, however, the result shows some deleted files.

I am looking for a git command that list only non deleted file in the git repo.

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation and set up the desired flags.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

You are looking for this:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard
```

> ***`-c / - -cached`***
>     Show cached files in the output (default)
>
> ***`-d / --deleted`***
>   Show deleted files in the output
>
> ***`-m / --modified`***
>   Show modified files in the output
>
> ***`-o / --others`***
>   Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output
>
> ***`-i / --ignored`***
>   Show only ignored files in the output. When showing files in the index, print only those matched by an exclude pattern. When showing "other" files, show only those matched by an exclude pattern.

---

Another option is to use the `git diff` with the `git-filter`

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A --cached
```

> ***`--diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)…​[*]]`***
>
> ```
> Select only files that are 
>   Added (A)   
>   Copied (C)   
>   Deleted (D)   
>   Modified (M)   
>   Renamed (R)
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to read the documentation, for some reasons, I could not figure out how to show non deleted files.

Comment: So here it is: `git ls-files -o  --exclude-standard`

Comment: I think I did not explain my question clear. I would like to list all the files that are not deleted in the repo.

Comment: Let me see if i get you, You want to list all the file in the repo right now. How can they be deleted? you can see the deleted file in the staging area.

I dont understand what you want to do.  How can yon have deleted files in the repository.

Comment: yes, for example when I list all the files in the repo using git ls-files, it shows files that do not exist in the repo folder any more.

Answer (score 2):

This script should print all modified and untracked files, then exclude removed if thus exist.

`git ls-files -o -m --exclude-standard | grep -vE "^$(git ls-files -d | paste -sd "|" -)$"`

Description:

- `git ls-files --other`- *shows other (i.e. untracked) files in the output*
- `git ls-files --modified`- *shows modified files in the output*
- `git ls-files` - *shows deleted files in the output*
- `git ls-files --exclude-standard` - *adds the standard Git exclusions: .git/info/exclude, .gitignore in each directory, and the user's global exclusion file.*
- `grep -vE PATTERN`  - *excludes from the output in accordance with a given pattern*
- `paste -sd "|" -` concatenates the output by lines with '|' symbol

Comment: How would this work with \0 terminated lines?